# Promise не не выполняет resolve через .then, а выполняет .catch

Tags: javascript, promise

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в Promise на JS.
Весь код здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/cyr7wuaL/

Простейший конвертер валют, задача написать через промисы.
На сколько я понял, по If я всегда должен попадать в resolve и через .then выполнять математические действия.
А я почему-то попадаю в .catch.
Или я неправильно понял смысл промисов, или где-то ошибка.

```
let inputRub = document.getElementById('rub'),
    inputUsd = document.getElementById('usd');

function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    inputRub.addEventListener('input', () => {
      let data = {
        usd:"60"
      }

      if (true) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }

    });
    });
}

getData()
    .then(()=>inputUsd.value = inputRub.value / data.usd)
    .catch(()=>inputUsd.value = "Не ОК");
```

Comment: Ну почему же. Вы попадаете в `.then` в котором пытаетесь использовать `data.usd`, но такой переменной нет и вы попадаете в `catch`. Кажется вам кроме промизов ещё стоит подучить область видимости переменных. https://learn.javascript.ru/closure

Comment: Ну и вообще конкретно этот код вообще не надо писать через промисы

Comment: @Alexey Ten, Спасибо. Статью изучил. Переместил объект data в глобальную область. Теперь resolve обрабатывает только первый введенный символ, последующие нет. https://jsfiddle.net/8djn6f02/ PS Да, тут промисы не нужны (в оригинале данные получаются через JSON), я тут просто упростил и пытаюсь разобраться с самим механизмом промисов.

Comment: «только первый введенный символ» — вот именно поэтому тут и не нужен промис. Он срабатывает ровно один раз. В общем вы выбрали неудачный пример.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, то есть я правильно понял, что вот этот простой код https://jsfiddle.net/8djn6f02/1/ невозможно переписать под использование промисов, чтобы он работал точно так же? (если опустить момент целессообразности, чисто технически)

Comment: В том виде который у вас написан точно нельзя.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, спасибо! А не подскажете, в какой вид нужно переделать, чтобы было можно переписать это на промисах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то еще будет нужно решение: нужно функцию getData() поместить в функцию обработчик inputRub, что бы она делала исчисления каждое нажатие. А объект data, нужно передать в resolve(data), что бы данный объект можно было достать из then, ну и получить объект data в методе .then(data)
код с решением здесь

```js
let inputRub = document.getElementById('rub'),
  inputUsd = document.getElementById('usd');

inputRub.addEventListener('input', () => {
  function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let data = {
        usd: "10"
      };

      if (true) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject();
      }

    });
  }

  getData()
    .then((data) => {
      inputUsd.value = inputRub.value / data.usd
    })
    .catch(() => inputUsd.value = "Не ОК");
})
```

```css
label {
            display: block;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        input {
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="rub">RUB</label>
    <input id="rub" type="text">
    <label for="usd">USD</label>
    <input id="usd" type="text">

</body>
</html>
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/mhaoLb1y/`